# Open Product of Certain Category in a new tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I am looking to make a select product category open the single product in a new tab. The other product category would behave as normal opening in the same tab.

Here is the code I have that works Globally for all products...

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );

add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'ami_function_open_new_tab', 10 );

function ami_function_open_new_tab() {
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';
}
```

This code works perfectly but I want to make it product Category Specific so here is what I came up with...

```
remove_action ( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'ami_function_open_new_tab', 10 );

function ami_function_open_new_tab() {

if ( has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';

 }else if( !has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    remove_action ( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'ami_function_open_new_tab', 10 );
    add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
 }
}
```

Works as expected except 1 problem

PROBLEM: the first product listed on pages for products not in the specific category dont open in a new tab or in the existing tab (wont open at all). the 2nd, 3rd,so on all open as expected.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that your remove_action can't take an action, and there are 2 links in a row. That's why the first one gives a trouble. Rest ones can be rendered by modern browser.
So try this code:

```
add_action('init',function(){ remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 ); } ,0);
function ami_function_open_new_tab() {
//....
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it with simple jQuery

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
if ( has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo '<script>

//for existing content
jQuery(".woocommerce-LoopProduct-link").attr("target","_blank");

//for content part which comes from AJAX
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
jQuery(".woocommerce-LoopProduct-link").attr("target","_blank");
});
</script>';
}
});
```

Comment: Awesome this worked like a charm! I used the 2nd jQuery code. Thank you for your expertise!

Comment: There is one caveat with this. I am using an AJAX load more plugin for the products rather than pagination, the initial loaded products open properly in a new tab but anything loaded after that opens in the same window. Is there an easy fix for this or no?

Comment: i have edited my answer. Check, if no success, let me know your URL

Comment: That was it. You rock!!